# When python is referred to as single threaded why does in not have the same pitfalls in processing as something like node.js?

Tags: python, list

I've been doing Node programming for a while and one thing I'm just very tired of is having to worry about blocking the event loop with anything that requires lots of cpu time. I'd also like to expand my language skills to something more focused on machine learning, so python seemed like a good choice based on what I've read.

However, I keep seeing that python is also single threaded, but I get the feeling this wording is being used in a different way than how it's usually used in node. Python is the go to language for a lot of heavy data manipulation so I can't imagine it blocks the same way node does. Can someone with more familiarity with python (and some with node) explain how their processing of concurrent requests differs when 1 request is cpu intensive?

Comment: Python suffers exactly the same way, I think. Why can't you imagine that it blocks the same way node does?

Answer (score 1):

First of all Python is not single-threaded, but its standard library contains everything required to manage threads. It works fine for IO bound tasks, but does not for CPU bound tasks because of the Global Interpretor Lock which prevents more than one thread to execute Python code at the same time.

For data processing tasks, several modules exist that add low level (C code level) processing and internally manage the GIL to be able to use multi-core processing. The most used modules here are scipy and numpy (scientific and numeric processing) and pandas which is an efficient data frame processing tools using numpy arrays for its underlying containers.

Long story short: For io bound tasks, Python is great. If your problem is *vectorizable* through numpy or pandas, Python is great. If your problem is CPU  intensive and neither numpy nor pandas will be used, Python is not at its best.

Comment: How does it compare to node.js? Could there also exist C code level modules like scipy, numpy or pandas with a Javascript binding?

Comment: @Trilarion: Could they exist? Probably, except that Python declares a C language interface from its early conception. But the core of Javascript is its execution inside browsers, so I'm unsure whether interfaces like that exist

Comment: I found node ffi (https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) which may be helpful there.